# How to hide Angular code form HTML

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to hide the Angular attributes like `ng-model` or `ng-repeat` form the compiled HTML output. The concern is that anyone can easily view the source of HTML which exposes the name of my Angular App, Controllers, Directives and so on.

Comment: Even if there's a way to hide it, you will also be hiding it in the client browser. And it'll not solve your concern at all. Why do you want to hide it anyway?

Comment: lets just say i don't want visitors to see that i've used Anuglar

Comment: No, you can not. Even if you don't use angularJS at all, advance users will know that you're **not** using angular. :P. Why do you not want them to know that you're using angular? If your concern is about security, Angular can be [Model-View-Whatever](https://plus.google.com/+AngularJS/posts/aZNVhj355G2) you want it to be. So good luck on it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not Hide completely but there are other solution like,

you can use tools for minify the sources. See [Google Clousure](https://developers.google.com/closure/) and [ng-min](https://github.com/btford/ngmin) for angular.js

Take a look at those projects that may be useful: [ng-boilerplate](http://joshdmiller.github.io/ng-boilerplate/#/home) and [yeoman - angularjs](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular), [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) , better is to build your project to single minified and uglified js file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't hide the code, But you can use tools for minify the sources, like grunt build, use grunt to build one single js file for you application

Answer (score -1):

No. Angular works through HTML attributes.
So it cannot be changed.